# POST payload not being read by PHP page

Tags: php

I'm sending data to a PHP page in the form of a POST request. On chrome dev tools I can see the POST with payload of:

> "username=T&password=t&cpassword=t&email=t&cemail=t"

My PHP file starts with the following:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cemail = $_POST['cemail'];

echo("Username: $username <br>Password: $password <br>cPassword: $cpassword <br>Email: $email <br>cEmail: $cemail");
....
```

However, the page just shows:

> Username: 
> Password: 
> cPassword: 
> Email: 
> cEmail:

Why is this and how can I make it so that $username, $password, $cpassword, $email and $cemail are  set?

EDIT: method for generating post data is as follows:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    window.alert("Form submitted");
    var username = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("username").value);
    var password = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("password").value);
    var cpassword = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cpassword").value);
    var email = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("email").value);
    var cemail = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cemail").value);

    var postData = "username=" +username + "&password=" + password + "&cpassword=" + cpassword + "&email=" + email + "&cemail=" + cemail;
    window.alert(postData);

    if (email != cemail) {
        window.alert("Emails do not match");
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Emails do not match";
        return false;
    }

    if (password != cpassword) {
        window.alert("Passwords do not match");
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Passwords do not match";
        return false;
    }

    if (email == "" || email == null) {
        window.alert("Email is blank");
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Email cannot be blank";
        return false;
    }

    if (password == "" || password == null) {
        window.alert("Password is blank");
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Password cannot be blank";
        return false;
    }

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
            window.alert("Response recieved: " + response);
            if (response == "New record created successfully") {
                window.alert("Registration successful");
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Registration successful!";
            } else {
                window.alert("Something went wrong... :(");
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Something went wrong... :(";
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "./handleRegistration.php", true);
    window.alert("xmlhttp open");
    xmlhttp.send(postData);
    window.alert("POSTED");
    return false;
}
</script>

<form name="heliosRegister" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
Username:<br>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" required>
<br><br>
Passsword:<br>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" required>
<br><br>
Confirm Passsword:<br>
<input id="cpassword" type="password" name="cpassword" required>
<br><br>
Email:<br>
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" required>
<br><br>
Confirm Email:<br>
<input id="cemail" type="text" name="cemail" required>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register"> <p id="response"></p>
</form>
```

EDIT 2:

Problem solved, forgot to add the header information when sending the POST.

Comment: That's a querystring which you access via `$_GET`, not `$_POST`

Comment: How is the data transferred?

Comment: @JohnConde - how do you know that? a application/x-www-form-urlencoded post request body is formatted the same as a querystring.

Comment: True. Let's see if the OP can provide more information as to exactly how they obtain that data.

Comment: ^ Might start with showing the HTML that generates the POST data

Comment: The HTML which generates the post data has been added

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I forgot to add the header info before POSTing:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postData.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Comment: oh.. well FormData would do that for you automatically. also, Content-length will be silently ignored and recalculated, XMLHttpRequest does not - the standards demands that it does not - allow you to specify content-length header.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var username = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("username").value);
var password = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("password").value);
var cpassword = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cpassword").value);
var email = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("email").value);
var cemail = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cemail").value);

var postData = "username=" +username + "&password=" + password + "&cpassword=" + cpassword + "&email=" + email + "&cemail=" + cemail;
```

with

```
var fd=new FormData();
fd.append("username",document.getElementById("username").value);
fd.append("password",document.getElementById("password").value);
fd.append("cpassword",document.getElementById("cpassword").value);
fd.append("email",document.getElementById("email").value);
fd.append("cemail",document.getElementById("cemail").value);
```

then use

```
xmlhttp.send(fd);
```

and i think it should work.
btw, $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
should have given you an obvious error! (Undefined index),
 while developing, use this code! much easier to spot several types of errors during development:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```